# R - adding page numbers to PDF

Tags: r, plot, sweave, r-grid

I'm having trouble adding page numbers to PDFs.  Here's how I'm inserting pages / plots:

```
pdf( file = pdfFilePath , width = 11 , height = 8.5  )
for ( ... ) {
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport( viewport( layout = grid.layout( 2 , 2 ) ) )
    ... print 4 plots ....
}
```

onefile seems to name a file by the page number, but I want the page numbers to appear in the same file.

**Edit**
I've modified @Gavin's code sample to produce a working version of mixing graphic types to get page numbers:

```
require(ggplot2)
pdf( file = "FILE_PATH_TO_SAVE_PDF_HERE" , width = 11 , height = 8.5  )
par( oma = c ( 4 , 4 , 4 , 4 ) , mar=c( 4 , 0 , 2 , 0 )  )
plot( 0:11 , type = "n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="n", xlab = "", ylab = ""  )
mtext( side = 3 , line = 0 , outer = TRUE  , cex = 1.5 , family="mono" , "Title" )
grid.newpage()
p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = runif(10)), aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
        geom_point()
vplayout <- function(x, y) {
    viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
}
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(1,2))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(2,1))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(2,2))
mtext( "1" , side = 1 , line = 3 , outer = TRUE , cex = .8 , family="mono"  )
dev.off()
```

Comment: This does beg the question of why you don't want to use one of the Sweave or Sweave-like systems to produce your PDFs. You don't even need to use LaTeX - you could use odfWeave and convert that to PDF if LaTeX is such a barrier to entry.

Comment: ...and if this were base graphics, I'd just add an outer margin (`par(oma = c(3,0,0,0))`) and add the page number via a `title(xlab = "pagenum", outer = TRUE)` call or a `mtext("pagenum", side = 1, outer = TRUE)` call. I don't know enough grid graphics to know the equivalent steps with it, however.

Comment: @Gavin - I'll need to look into Sweave some more, but honestly this seems like a very basic scenario.  If R gives me the ability to print multiple pages to a PDF then I would expect to add page number out-of-the-box.

Comment: @SFun28 There **is** a facility in R that prints page numbers out of the box.  It's called SWeave.  Learn it.

Comment: @SFun28 Why? The `pdf()` device is for plotting PDF figures. It is not a device for PDF _documents_. That is an important distinction, which you seem to be conflating. Your presumption that because `pdf()` allows for quite sophisticated control of the dimensions of the outputted PDF it is suitable for these document processing tasks is incorrect; it (adding page numbers) might be a basic scenario for the latter, but the `pdf()` device was not intended to be used as the latter.

Comment: @Andrie - chill out =)  R is a platform.  A good platform enables flexability for two people to achieve the same sort of results using different methods.  Wouldn't it suck if there was only one way to close a window in Windows?

Comment: To the downvoters: that is a bit harsh. Ok, the OP should perhaps be looking at the Sweave-like tools, but the general premise of the Q is not wrong, and we must remember that Sweave requires some prep-work and knowledge of a document processing language. There is an easy answer with base graphics, but how to do the same with grid?

Comment: @Gavin - Where does it state that that is the sole purpose of the pdf device? =)  R is a platform.  It gives me the ability to create multi-page PDFs.  My scenarios might be different from yours or other peoples.  In particular, I enjoy document creation/population from R.  The workflow is really clean and straightforward for my scenarios.  I'm just trying to add a bit of formatting.  Yeah, it might not be super easy to do that, but it does not invalidate my scenarios or workflows.

Comment: @Gavin - thanks for the support.  agreed that the downvotes are a bit harsh (and IMO narrow-minded)

Comment: OK.  Here's an alternative.  And I am being dead serious.  I don't like SWeave myself, and have never used it, probably for the same reason you don't.  So I wrote a report writing system that uses R to output latex code.  I then let Latex do the typesetting, including the page numbering.  In this way I get the best of both worlds, without ever having to SWeave.  Perhaps one day I'll turn it into a package and publish it, but sadly at the moment it's too interwoven into a larger, as yet unpublished, package.

Comment: @Andrie - I like that solution.  It suits my purposes a lot better.  Ideally I'd still pursue the all-in-R solution (my documents are very simple - cover page followed by lots of plots, that's it =), but I could see myself doing what you proposed.

Comment: @SFun28 I didn't say it did and I think you a reading into it more than was intended - I am just pointing out that your presumption is wrong; documentation can't cover everything a fun doesn't do. `pdf()` just takes the low-level *drawing* commands and _draws_ on the "device" to produce a PDF file. It wasn't designed to do the things you want so you need to find workarounds like the the base graphics suggestion I supplied in my comment above. I think you can improve your workflow, hence comment one, but I appreciate there are other workflows hence my base solution after the Sweave trolling ;-)

Comment: @SFun28: If you expect the PDF device driver to automatically add page numbers, you're more than welcome to make that contribution.  If you're not willing / able to make that contribution, you might refrain from telling volunteers what they should have done.

Comment: @SFun28 What are the plotting commands - lattice, ggplot2 or custom grid? - if we can see some of those it might be possible be leverage some of the ggplot or lattice code/functionality to do something like the base graphics solution I suggested above.

Comment: @Gavin - noted and I appreciated your advice/viewpoint on this.  In defense of the all-in-R approach, I'm finding that my various formatting tasks are actually quite easy to perform in R and that the biggest barrier is that I'm new to R and still ramping-up.  That is, the workarounds are easy to implement once I'm pointed in the right direction.  I think that's a testament to the power of R.  Really appreciated your support on the Sweave trolling =)  thanks!

Comment: @Joshua - woah!  where did I tell volunteers what they should have done???

Comment: @SFun28: "If R gives me the ability to print multiple pages to a PDF then I would expect to add page number out-of-the-box."  I.e. the `pdf` function authors should have included functionality to add page numbers.

Comment: @Gavin - I'm using ggplot2.  Fairly simple stuff - I call grid.newpage() then pushViewport as show above.  After that I just print my ggplot2 plots using vp = viewport( row , column )

Comment: @Joshua - sigh...so much is lost in translation with text/message boards.  =)  I wasn't suggesting that the R authors messed up or anything like that.  I have not-unresonable expectations for many platforms.  When those expectations are not met, I'm not pointing fingers at the authors...I'll just find a workaround.  I'm super impressed with R.  Its not crazy that a new user such as I would expect a page number feature....

Comment: ...I think my comments make sense if you divorce the expectation from the finger-pointing because I'm not pointing any fingers - I'm really impressed with R and its totally ok to me that my expectation for this feature is not met. =)

Comment: @SFun28 I've added something (crude) as an answer. The basic idea is to add an extra viewport in your layout that spans the entire width of the device, but only has a small height. You can place the page number as a `textGrob()` into this small viewport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my second comment on the Q, I suggested a base graphics solution using `mtext()`. This appears to work for the OP so I show an expanded version here:

**Base Graphics:**

```
op <- par(oma = c(2,0,0,0))
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
mtext(side = 1, text = "Page 1", outer = TRUE)
layout(1)
par(op)
```

Resulting in:

[image: base graphics page number example]

@SFun28 reports this idea works for his ggplot/grid graphics too, but it does not for me. After running the last line of the code chunk below I get the following error:

```
> mtext(side = 1, text = "Page 1")
Error in mtext(side = 1, text = "Page 1") : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

which is indicative of the warning not to mix base and grid graphics.

```
require(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(data.frame(X = 1:10, Y = runif(10)), aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
        geom_point()
vplayout <- function(x, y) {
    viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
}
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(2, 2)))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(1,2))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(2,1))
print(p1, vp = vplayout(2,2))
mtext(side = 1, text = "Page 1")
```

Comment: take a look at the edited code.  thoughts?  btw...SO says that my edit will only appear after it has been peer reviewed.

Comment: @SFun28 I can't see your edits anywhere not even in the area where mod/10K+ rep people can approve edits from users with insufficient rep. Did you commit the edits? Perhaps try again?

Comment: I re-posted the edit (this time in the original question - take a look above).  There wasn't a commit option...apparently SO doesn't like it when people edit other people's posts.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified an [example](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/objectgrid-framelayout.R) from Paul Murrell's [R Graphics](http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/RGraphics/rgraphics.html) [book](http://www.crcpress.com/ecommerce_product/product_detail.jsf?catno=C486X&isbn=0000000000000&parent_id=&pc=) that draws an entire plot using grid and then places a label at the bottom in a separate viewport. I leave the fine tuning to the OP as I don't know what the individual plots are doing, but the general idea of creating an extra viewport (?) across the bottom of the device into which the label is drawn should map onto the `grid.layout()` ideas already used by @SFun28:

```
label <- textGrob("A page number! ",
                  x=0.5, y = 1.0, just="centre")
x <- seq(0.1, 0.9, length=50)
y <- runif(50, 0.1, 0.9)
gplot <- 
  gTree(
    children=gList(rectGrob(gp=gpar(col="grey60",
                                    fill="white")),
                   linesGrob(x, y), 
                   pointsGrob(x, y, pch=16, 
                              size=unit(1.5, "mm"))),
    vp=viewport(width=unit(1, "npc") - unit(5, "mm"), 
                height=unit(1, "npc") - unit(10, "mm")))



layout <- grid.layout(2, 1,
                      widths=unit(c(1, 1), 
                                  c("null", "grobwidth"),
                                  list(NULL, label)),
                      heights = unit(c(1, 1),
                                     c("null", "grobheight"),
                                     list(NULL, label)))

grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="grey60", fill="grey90"))
pushViewport(viewport(layout=layout))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=2))
grid.draw(label)
popViewport()
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=1))
grid.draw(gplot)
popViewport(2)
```

Which gives:

[image: A grid page number example]

Comment: Sorry this is a bit complex but as I said, my grid-fu is weak. If some reproducible ggplot code to draw the actual plots had been made available I might have been convinced to try a complete solution...

Comment: @Gavin - actually, I think your proposed solution in the question comments works.  I simply added mtext(...) after all of my plots are drawn and it puts the page number in!  Still need to do more testing....

Comment: @SFun28 be careful - you are not supposed to mix grid and base graphics. But if it works for you, great!

Comment: @Gavin - confirmed, it worked!  Would you mind converting your comment into an answer so I can give you credit?  also, just curious - why shouldn't I mix grid and base graphics?

Comment: @SFun28 grid and base graphics are two fundamentally different infrastructures for producing plots in R. They weren't designed to work together so you pays you money and takes your chance if you do mix them.

Comment: @SFun28 It doesn't work for me, the mixing of base and grid graphics. See my second Answer.

Comment: @Gavin - I'll try to fix up your example

Comment: @Gavin (+1) Really nice. Sidenote: [gridBase](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridBase/index.html) might help to mix base and grid graphics.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
plots = replicate(8, qplot(1,1))
library(gridExtra)
p <- 
do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(ncol=2, nrow=2, top =NULL, 
        bottom = quote(quote(paste(g, "/",pages))))))

p

ggsave("multipage.pdf", p)
```

(the `quote(quote())` is needed to maintain lazy evaluation, somehow)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Gavin, I also encountered the error when mixing ggplot with mtext.

Here is what works really nicely for me when using ggplot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
printWithFooter = function(gg_obj, bottom_left = NULL, bottom_right = NULL) 
{
  print(gg_obj)
  if (!is.null(bottom_right))
  {
    label = textGrob(bottom_right,
                     x = 0.98,  # right side
                     y = 0.0,   # bottom
                     just="right", 
                     hjust = NULL,
                     vjust = -.5,
                     gp=gpar(fontsize=7, col="#333333"))
    grid.draw(label)
  }
  if (!is.null(bottom_left))
  {
    label = textGrob(bottom_left,
                     x = 0.02,  # left side
                     y = 0.0,   # bottom
                     just="left", 
                     hjust = NULL,
                     vjust = -.5,
                     gp=gpar(fontsize=7, col="#333333"))  
    grid.draw(label)
  }
}

## example

d = data.frame(x = runif(1:20), y = runif(1:20), facet = rep(1:4, each=5))
p = ggplot(d) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y)) + facet_wrap(~facet)
printWithFooter(p, "left", "right")
```

[image: Example result]