# ggplot2: Why Does Semi-Transparency + pdflatex Cause Heavier-Than-Normal PDF Fonts?

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2: Why Does Semi-Transparency + pdflatex Cause Heavier-Than-Normal PDF Fonts?

I've run into a problem where `pdf()`ing in R and then `pdflatex`-ing a ggplot2 image causes all of the text on the same page as the image to become emboldened, but only when `alpha` < 1. Here's a minimal example in R:

```
require("ggplot2")
"%_%" <- function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep="")
test <- function(filename, alpha)
{
  pdf(filename %_% "-fig.pdf")
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(alpha=alpha)
  print(p); dev.off()

  latexDocument <- c(
    "\\documentclass{article}",
    "\\usepackage{Sweave}",
    "%\\pdfpageattr{/Group <</S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}",
    "\\begin{document}",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
    "\\begin{figure}",
    "\\includegraphics{" %_% filename %_% "-fig}",
    "  \\caption{Figure Caption}",
    "\\end{figure}",
    "\\end{document}")

  con <- file(filename %_% ".tex"); writeLines(latexDocument, con); close(con)
  system("pdflatex " %_% filename)
}

test("test1", 1)
test("test2", 0.3)
```

Comparing the output files *test1.pdf* and *test2.pdf*, I notice that the latter document has heavier fonts when viewed in Acrobat or Acrobat Reader. The problem has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752170/ggplot2-adding-alpha-parameter-makes-all-other-text-darker-bold-in-pdf) before, but to no resolution.

I can't seem to solve the problem, which messes up the look of reports I generate with Sweave. Does anyone have any insight into it? I'm using R version 2.13.1 on Windows.

Comment: I thought that the poster of that question, @SFun28, had offered a solution ... use ghostscript.

Comment: @SFun28 wasn't explicit in his solution, but I tried using `embedFonts()` in R and also ghostscript to touch the file: `gswin32c.exe -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=./test2gs.pdf ./test2.pdf`. Both of these decreased the file size, but neither corrected the heavier font.

Comment: Do you see the heavier fonts when you look at test1-fig.pdf and test2-fig.pdf?  Or is the difference only discernible after running it through pdxlatex?

Comment: The difference in the fonts' appearance between _test1-fig.pdf_ and _test2-fig.pdf_ is the same as that between the `pdflatex` output: the latter file has heavier-looking fonts. So yes, it seems to begin with the `pdf()`-created images.

Comment: what happens when you have both on the same file? For instance, `p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) ; library(gridExtra) ; ggsave("test.pdf", arrangeGrob(p + geom_point(), p + geom_point(alpha=0.2)))
`

Comment: @baptiste: I'll try out your code, but I first noticed this phenomenon in an Sweave-generated report on a page that contained text, ggplot graphics, and base graphics; all the text on the page looked heavier.

Comment: It would be interesting to try to do this with as reduced a graph as possible (e.g. make a theme with almost no elements, plot a single point) in order to be able to compare the PDF files and see what is actually different at the level of the PDF ... rather than the (admittedly reasonably effective) empirical approach, squinting at the output in different viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `pdf()` function with an argument, `colormodel = "cmyk"`?

```
require("ggplot2")
pdf("test_cmyk.pdf", colormodel = "cmyk")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.2) +
  opts(title = "cmyk, alpha = 0.2")
dev.off()
embedFonts("test_cmyk.pdf")
```

It seems to be slightly better than `colormodel = "rgb"` in my environment (Win XP, Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro).

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. This appears to be a fix to the "problem" when the problem actually exists.

Comment: From the various tests, it seems plausible that there is a buglet in the pdf device, or at least an unexpected feature, when the file contains semi-transparent material. To narrow it down, one could try to plot a minimal example that does not rely on `ggplot2`. `library(grid); grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="blue", alpha=0.2)) ; grid.text("test")` vs. alpha=1.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I made an inquiry to Adobe Systems Inc. about this problem.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer. Although it doesn't explicitly answer "Why?" it provides a decent solution to a problem whose cause may be intermittent or limited to a subset of PDF viewers, in which case the question itself might be too broad.

Comment: Adobe Systems Inc.'s support was responsive, but they did not provide any solution and information....  From now on I will be handled this way for this problem.  Thank you for your meaningful topic!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to see if it's a problem with R or ggplot2 or Sweave or pdflatex, or simply your pdf viewer? I cannot reproduce the problem. Here's a screenshot using Adobe Reader on Mac OS 10.6,
[image]

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  grid      methods        base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.9 proto_0.3-9.2 reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.6
```

Comment: According to @priscian, apparently not Sweave or pdflatex since it is seen in the direct pdf files created by `pdf()`

Comment: @Brian Diggs indeed. Next step is to use grid instead of `ggplot2`, or even base graphics.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a matter of anti-aliasing making the text look bolder/bigger.  I can see it on the axis title, but not labels.  And it is more pronounced at lower magnifications.  I can't prove anything, and a diff of the two PDFs was not enlightening to me.

At 200%:

[image: View of PDFs in Acrobat Reader at 200%]

At 800%:

[image: View of PDFs in Acrobat Reader at 800%]

Generated using the following code (which eliminates the Sweave and pdflatex steps)

```
require("ggplot2")
"%_%" <- function(a, b) paste(a, b, sep="")
test <- function(filename, alpha)
{
  pdf(filename %_% "-fig.pdf")
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(alpha=alpha)
  print(p); dev.off()
}

test("test1", 1)
test("test2", 0.3)
```

Session info:

```
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtable_1.5-6         ggplot2_0.8.9        proto_0.3-9.2       
[4] reshape_0.8.4        plyr_1.6             microbenchmark_1.1-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.5.0 tools_2.13.1
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, especially at lower magnifications. Interestingly, I _don't_ see font weight differences in the TeXworks PDF viewer (based on the [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) library). This "problem" may indeed be just a matter of anti-aliasing tied to the viewer, as you've said, and as such doesn't need a solution. Thanks for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Does this thread from the ggplot2 mailing list help at all?

http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/80016f7ac2a28f28/7f5b7f2c1bd9f716

The upshot is to try puttting the following line in the preamble of your LaTeX document:

```
\pdfpageattr {/Group << /S /Transparency /I true /CS /DeviceRGB>>}
```

If you follow the links from the ggplot2 mailing list thread discussion, you'll find the thread with this potential solution ultimately posted at:

http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2007-December/007480.html

Hope that helps, but I see Baptiste has weighed in both here and on the ggplot2 question, so perhaps this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I've added a LaTeX-commented `\pdfpageattr` line into my original code for anyone who wants to test its addition. In Acrobat Reader I noticed a shifting of the boldness from the plot text to the document body with the addition but, as above, YMMV. In any case, it doesn't seem to represent a complete "fix" of the problem, but maybe someone else who reads this will be able to synthesize the complete problem/solution from the testing we've already done. Thanks.