# Adding page numbers in pdf file generated by R

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I am trying to add page numbers to a pdf file generated using plot in R and saved in a pdf format.
I am using `d_pply` to the `data.frame` within which I am using the plot command.

I thought `d_pply` would help me in avoiding a `for` loop. Below is the sample from my original data with many more factors.

```
data1 <- structure(list(fact = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), speed = c(10.56, 
11.94, 13.61, 15, 16.67, 18.06, 19.44, 20.28, 21.11, 21.67, 22.5, 
23.06, 23.61, 24.44, 25, 25.56, 26.11, 26.94, 27.5, 15.83, 16.67, 
17.5, 18.06, 18.89, 19.72, 20.56, 21.11, 21.94, 22.5, 23.33, 
23.89, 24.44, 25, 25.56, 26.11, 26.67, 27.22, 8.61, 10.28, 11.94, 
13.61, 15, 16.39, 17.5, 18.89, 19.72, 20.83, 21.67, 22.22, 22.5, 
23.06, 23.61, 23.89, 23.89, 23.61)), .Names = c("fact", "speed"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -55L))
```

*I tried to accomplish the task by using a global index*. But I am looking for an efficient way to do this. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735541/r-adding-page-numbers-to-pdf) did not quite help me.

```
index1 <<- 0
plot_pg <- function(x)
{ index1 <<- index1+1
  plot(x$speed,main=paste0('pg# ',index1))
}

genplot <- function(df1,filename1)
{
  pdfNAME <- paste0(name1,'.pdf')
  pdf(pdfNAME)
    d_ply(df1,c('fact'),function(x) plot_pg(x))
  dev.off()
}
genplot(data1,'data1Plots')
```

**Update**

I should mention here that I would be splitting my `data.frame` by more than one variables..something like `ddply(data,c('var1','var2'),function(x) MyplotFunc(x))`

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: The example data here shows only two factors but I have actually about 480 of them and that may also increase in future. DO you think `for` loop will be efficient? Anyway, how will you do it using a `for` loop without a 'apply' family of functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply do this:

```
genplot <- function(df1,filename1){
  pdfNAME <- paste0(filename1,'.pdf')
  tmp <- split(df1,df1$fact)
  pdf(pdfNAME)
  for (i in seq_along(tmp)){
    plot(tmp[[i]][,'speed'],main = paste0("pg#",i))
  }
  dev.off()
}
```

The idea that `for` loops are *inherently* slow is a myth. The issue is that it can be easy to slip into bad coding techniques *inside* the for loop that makes the operations you're doing take a long time.

In this case, all you're doing in the for loop is plotting, so I doubt there will be much of a performance difference between this and using something like `lapply`. The things to watch out for are growing objects (i.e. appending) and modifying objects, since both will result in excessive copying.

Comment: Another reason I was using `d_pply` was that I had to split the `data.frame` by more than one variable. But I could not get `split` to work in that case. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Stat-R Read the documentation: "a ‘factor’ in the sense that as.factor(f) defines the grouping, or a list of such factors in which case their interaction is used for the grouping."

Comment: `R` went into infinite loop when I wrote `tmp <- split(df1,as.list(df1$fact,df1$fac2))`, where `fac2` is the second factor. Do you know why? 'tmp <- split(df1,list(df1$fact,df1$fac2))' worked finally...